# The chromatic splitting conjecture and functoriality

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, bousfield-localization

Let $M$ be a finite spectrum, so that $L_{K(n)} M = M \wedge L_{K(n)} S$. Recall that (a weak version of) the chromatic splitting conjecture states that the chromatic attaching map $L_{n-1} M \to L_{n-1} L_{K(n)} M$ (which appears in the chromatic fracture square) admits a splitting. The chromatic splitting conjecture is true for the sphere spectrum $S$ if and only if it is true for every finite spectrum $M$. One nice consequence of the chromatic splitting conjecture is the existence of maps
$$f_M: L_{K(n)} M \to L_{n-1} L_{K(n)} M \xrightarrow{\text{splitting}} L_{n-1} M \to L_{K(n-1)} M,$$
such that the homotopy limit of the tower $\{L_{K(n)} M\}$ is equivalent to $\text{holim } L_n M$. When $M$ is a finite $p$-local spectrum, this is just $M$ itself (there are more general conditions, but this is the simplest to state). The map $f_M$ described above is functorial in $M$ (since $f_M = M \wedge f_S$). In particular, if there is an *infinite loop* map $\alpha:\Omega^\infty M \to \Omega^\infty N$ (which defines a map $\alpha':M \to N$), we obtain a commutative square
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
L_{K(n)} M & \xrightarrow{L_{K(n)} \alpha'} & L_{K(n)} N \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
L_{K(n-1)} M & \xrightarrow{L_{K(n)} \alpha'} & L_{K(n-1)} N.
\end{array}
$$
However, if $\alpha:\Omega^\infty M \to \Omega^\infty N$ is a map which does not necessarily deloop, the $K(n)$-local Bousfield-Kuhn functor $\Phi_n$ *still* gives a map $L_{K(n)} M \to L_{K(n)} N$ for every $n$. My question, roughly, is "how compatible is the map $f_?$ defined above with the Bousfield-Kuhn functor"? More precisely:

Assume the chromatic splitting conjecture for the sphere (equivalently, for all finite spectra), and let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the full subcategory of pointed topological spaces spanned by the zeroth spaces of finite spectra. (Importantly, the morphisms are maps of spaces which are not necessarily deloopable.) Is there a natural transformation $\Phi_n \to \Phi_{n-1}$ of functors $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathrm{Top}_\ast \to \mathrm{Sp}$?